# Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a map and $P,Q \subseteq A$.Show that $f_* (P) - f_* (Q) \subseteq f_* (P - Q)$,

Tags: functions

> Let  $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a map and $P,Q \subseteq A$.Show that 
>   $f_* (P) - f_* (Q) \subseteq f_* (P - Q)$. Note $f_* (A)$ mean image of the
>   set A.

I tried to take an element in $f_* (P) - f_* (Q)$ and derive from it but I can't see the path.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element $x$ in $f_*(P)\setminus f_*(Q)$ is characterized by the existence of a $p\in P$ such that $f(p)=x$. Furthermore, it is $f(q)\neq x$ for all elements in $Q$. That implies in particular that $p$ cannot be an element of $Q$. Therefore, $p\in P\setminus Q$ and it follows that $x$ is contained in $f_*(P\setminus Q)$.

Comment: I didn't understand how p cannot be an element of Q.I mean, yes there is some  $p \in P$ which is not in Q, but if you look up the definition of P - Q, you will see that {$p | p \in P$ and $p \not\in Q $}.As you see some p's are in Q.

Comment: If $p$ were an element of $Q$, then x would also qualify as an element of the image of $Q$ and therefore not be an element of the set $f_*(P)\setminus f_*(Q)$. This is precisely the set of elements, which are in the image of $P$, but not in the image of $Q$.

Comment: when we say "p is an element of Q", we say basically "{$p for all p in \in Q$}" , but I'm saying that there is some p values that are not in Q but it does't mean that none of the p values are in Q, meaning P and Q might have some intersection.Therefore, you can not say directly $f(q)\not = x$ for all $q \in Q$

Comment: No, that is not what we say. We have a special $p$ here, which has the additional property that its image $x$ is in the set on the left hand side. This in turn makes it impossible for this specific $p$ to also be an element of $Q$.

Comment: You are right, thanks.